# jquery - referencing a jquery object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I'm using the ui library, and I have something like:

```
$('#trash-bin').droppable({
        tolerance: 'touch',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            alert(ui.draggable.id + " was dropped");
        }
    });
    $('#images').draggable({});
```

Which I know is wrong (the alert says "undefined dropped")

How can I reference the image's id that was dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stated in the documentations that the `ui.draggable` object is a jQuery object, not the original DOM element:

> `ui.draggable` - current draggable element, a jQuery object.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

So you'll have to use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function instead:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.draggable.attr('id') + " was dropped");
}
```